# Magmi Not Importing When CSV Files Contains Commas

Tags: magento, csv, import, magmi

I have installed and made some successful product imports in to Magento using Magmi, but as soon as I try to import any data where the spreedsheet columns have commas [,] Magmi will not perform the import.

For example when I save the data in this speadsheet as a CSV file Magmi successfully imports the data;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx1KP.png

However, Magmi refuses to import the data in the table below, where you can see in column F I have added data that include 'commas'.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w28Ao.png

Can anyone advise. I am using an Apple Mac with OpenOffice to prepare and save my data.

Comment: Please post a raw, text snippet of both your CSV files in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is the data not importing entirely, or is just the visibility column not being set?

Visibility is a Magento core attribute which Magmi can set by using exact numerical option id value.

Generally, the option values you want to use for the visibility field are as follows:

**Not Visible Individually =** `1`
**Catalog =** `2`
**Search =** `3`
**Catalog, Search =** `4`

So in your case, if you want to set these products to **Catalog, Search**, you can set the visibility column value to `4`.

To double-check that the above mapping is correct for your instance of Magento, the easiest way is as follows:

1. Go edit any product
2. Look for the Visibility drop down field, and **right click > inspect element**
3. In the developer tools, take note the values associated to each label.

Below an example of the process and what to look for.

[image: Magento Visbility Field Values]

Answer (score 0):

Axel is correct, you should set the data to the numerical value 4.

But I do also recommend you explore a better way to export CSV content from Open Office. You may have to start a new document because I find I only see the dialogue below once and then I never see it again. Create a new document, paste your data into it. Choose save-as, select CSV, and save it. Eventually you should see the dialogue below. Change the encoding to UTF 8, the text delimiter to " and tick the 'Quote all text cells' box.

Then you should be able to have any cells with commas or other things in them. Always ensure you CSV files are quoted. "like","this","so you, can","have commas, in them". It is worth inspecting your CSV file in a text editor to see the format is as expected before uploading it to MAGMI.

[image: Open Office and Libre Office ask what CSV format you want]

Comment: When you do a Save as, there's a check box for the rather cryptic "Edit filter settings". Check that and you'll see the export dialogue box every time!